# PivotViewer is very slow on loading my collection

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, azure, pivotviewer

PivotViewer is very slow on loading my collection(34mbs) 344 images. What should i do?.
My app is on Windows Azure so my bandwith is ok. Is there any optimazation? at least to load an ammount of images while wating others to load. Cause now i m stuck to the "LOADING" screen for like 4 mins +.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to set the cxml file to Content Build.

Answer (score 1):

Are you generating the pivot collection on the fly or is it precreated? The creation of the Deep Zoom files can take a while.

We have a Pivot Collection with over 11,000 images hosted in Azure, and while not the fastest loading page in the world, it does load faster than the times you are indicating. However, the Deep Zoom file is created every evening and not done dynamically.

http://www.appletoncompassion.org/VirtualExhibitViewer